# opening database from file - android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite

I am currently trying to work out how to use a SQLiteDatabase for a vocabulary app. At the moment I just have a test-database to look if its working. Apparently it doesn't work:

```
06-05 20:29:14.942 21532-21532/de.dev.jana.applicationtest E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
  Process: de.dev.jana.applicationtest, PID: 21532
  java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:293)
      at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5201)
      at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21163)
      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:746)
      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5443)
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:728)
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
   Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:288)
      at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5201) 
      at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21163) 
      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:746) 
      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5443) 
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:728) 
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618) 
   Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: test (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT * FROM test
      at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
      at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:887)
      at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:498)
      at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
      at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
      at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.<init>(SQLiteStatement.java:31)
      at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.executeSql(SQLiteDatabase.java:1674)
      at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.execSQL(SQLiteDatabase.java:1605)
      at de.dev.jana.applicationtest.Model.getFirstFolderName(Model.java:27)
      at de.dev.jana.applicationtest.MainActivity.onButtonClick(MainActivity.java:38)
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:288) 
      at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5201) 
      at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21163) 
      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:746) 
      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5443) 
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:728) 
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
```

I need to have access to the database in different activities, so I need to make the database globally accessable. Therefore I have created an application in which the DatabaseHelper gets created. From there all the activites can access the Database.

The Application:

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {

private static SQLiteDatabase database;

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    DatabaseHelper dbHelper = DatabaseHelper.getInstance(this);
    database = dbHelper.getReadableDatabase();
}

public static SQLiteDatabase getReadableDatabase() {
    return database;
}
}
```

The DatabaseHelper:

```
class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

private static DatabaseHelper instance = null;

private DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, "test.db", null, 1);
}

public static DatabaseHelper getInstance(Context context) {
    if(instance == null)
        instance = new DatabaseHelper(context);
    return instance;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL("PRAGMA foreign_keys=ON;");
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

}
}
```

In another class I try to use the information from the database. When I try to query the database I get the exception. It says that the table wouldn't exist. But it certainly does exist in the database file. I have checked this multiple times.

When I press a button the getFirstFolderName() method gets called at some point.

```
public class Model {

private SQLiteDatabase db;

public Model() {
    db = MyApplication.getReadableDatabase();
}

public String getFirstFolderName() {

    String query = "select * from test;";
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null); // <- here is the problem

    cursor.moveToFirst();
    int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex("text");

    String name = cursor.getString(columnIndex);

    cursor.close();

    return name;

}
}
```

I have searched a lot about this problem. In all the other examples they have created the database in the onCreate method. But I am opening a file from the assets folder. Is there the problem?

I have seen old examples of how to open a database, but I guess those are outdated. Can one open a database file just from passing the correct file name into the super-constructor the SQLiteOpenHelper? In the API is written that "this class takes care of opening the database if it exists, creating it if it does not, and upgrading it as necessary. Transactions are used to make sure the database is always in a sensible state."
 Or do I have to type it in all manually, like in [this](https://blog.reigndesign.com/blog/using-your-own-sqlite-database-in-android-applicaons/) example (from 2009)?

EDIT: I have found the solution. Stupidly simple. I now use the libary SQLiteAssetHelper.

Comment: What columns does the `test` table contain? How should the `SQLiteOpenHelper` know?

Comment: it contains the column "id" and "text". I guess the SQLiteOpenHelper knows that from just opening the database.